# How to fix an issue that code changes are not reflecting in PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2, process-management

In my PM2 instance running on Windows server having 4 cores CPU and that many clusters/instances, file changes are caught and servers get restarted but the changes do not get reflected. Instead it continues to show the old updates/features.

But when I tried doing the following it starts reflecting the new updates.

```
$ pm2 stop all
$ pm2 kill 
$ pm2 start... (one by one)
```

This does not happen always but happens sometime only. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem in AWS deployment. Then I come up with a solution after long research and this worked for me as a charm.

After `git pull` just stop your server and then start it. After that

1. `pm2 start index.js`
2. `pm2 reload index`

Now your changes are reflected.

Comment: doesn't work if you have running connections

Comment: Just stop your server and start it. Then follow the process mentioned above.

Comment: Make sure to run your build command or whatever it is.